# Find which related column the user has

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem. I have a `user` who lives in a `country` and may have one or more `interests`.

I just want to know what `code` this user has.
For example, the user who lives in `Germany` and has `Gaming` and `Swimming` as interests has the codes `03` and `02`. I would like to output these as well.

Dataframe

```py
   country  interest code
0  Germany     Sport   01
1  Germany  Swimming   02
2  Germany    Gaming   03
3  Hungary     Sport   11
4  Hungary  Swimming   12
```

Code

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'country': ['Germany', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'Hungary', 'Hungary'],
     'interest': ['Sport', 'Swimming', 'Gaming', 'Sport', 'Swimming'],
     'code': ['01', '02','03', '11', '12'],}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

print(df)

user_country = 'Germany'
user_interest = ['Sport',]

df_country = df[df['country'] == user_bundesland]
for interest in df_country['interest'].tolist():
    if(interest in user_interesse):
      print(interest)
```

What I want (example)

```py
user_country = 'Germany'
user_interest = ['Sport',]


[OUT] [01]


user_country = 'Hungary'
user_interest = ['Sport', 'Swimming']


[OUT] [11, 12]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `user_country` is a string and `user_interest` is a list of strings, you can subset your `df` by the country and list of one or more interests:

```
user_country = 'Germany'
user_interest = ['Sport','Swimming']

user_codes = df[(df['country'] == user_country) & (df['interest'].isin(user_interest))]['code'].tolist()
```

The output of `user_codes` is:

```
>>> user_codes
['01', '02']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And how to check if `user_interest=['SPORT, 'SWIMMING]`- so if the list is uppercase.

Comment: @Test if your `user_interest` list has to be uppercase for some reason (maybe it's an input from somewhere else), then you should probably make the corresponding column in your `df` uppercase too, which you can do using `df['interest'] = df['interest'].str.upper()` before running the line from my answer that creates the list `user_codes`

Answer (score 2):

Using [`df.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
user_codes = df.query('country == "Hungary" and 
                      (interest == "Sport" or interest == "Swimming")  \
         ')['code'].tolist()

user_codes

>> [11, 12]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And how to check if `user_interest=['SPORT, 'SWIMMING]` - so if the list is uppercase.